# how to identify Chrome processes launched by ChromeDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Browser.cs:

```
 public static ChromeDriver GetChromeDriver(string machine)
    {

        String chromeLocalAppDataPath = GetChromeLocations(machine); //"d:\ChromeTest\Google\Chrome\User Data\Auto\";

        var headless = true;
        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("--no-experiments");
        options.AddArgument("disable-infobars");
        options.AddArgument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36");
        if (headless)
            options.AddArgument("headless");
        options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");


        options.AddArguments("user-data-dir=" + chromeLocalAppDataPath);

        options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
        return new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
```

Run:

```
var driver = Browser.GetChromeDriver("P1");  // user profile 1
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com/");
```

basically I build these small app to call up multiple Chrome instances, now I wonder if there's a way to identify the processes from another app, so in case I want to delete specified chrome processes that are launched by Profile 1 from **Process.GetProcessesByName("chromedriver")**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create some shared memory to identify process ids. [MemoryMapped files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files) could be one solution, database/WCF, named piped IPC etc.

That is because you can get the process id from your web driver by using [ChromeDriverService](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeDriverService.htm)

1. Create the WebDriver by using `ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService, ChromeOptions)`

```
var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
var webDriver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```

2. Get the processId from your service, or save the services so that they can be globally accessible in your application (by having some kind of singleton store or something like that)
3. Update the shared memory or the communicating application by the stored in memory data

There is no straightforward way I can think that does not require quite an effort.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the identify the Chrome process that was launched by chromedriver then the following is a solution.  This example is in C#.  There would be the same implementation for other languages (like Java) but I am only working in C#.

Chrome allows you to supply your own user-defined command-line arguments.  So you can add an argument named "scriptpid-" with the PID (Windows Process ID) of your currently running program.  ChromeDriver passes your argument to Chrome in the command-line.  Then using Windows WMI calls retrieve this PID from the command-line of the running Chrome ...

```
public static IntPtr CurrentBrowserHwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
public static int CurrentBrowserPID = -1;
        
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("scriptpid-" + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

// Get the PID and HWND details for a chrome browser

System.Diagnostics.Process[] processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
for (int p = 0; p < processes.Length; p++)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher commandLineSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " + processes[p].Id);
    String commandLine = "";
    foreach (ManagementObject commandLineObject in commandLineSearcher.Get())
    {
        commandLine += (String)commandLineObject["CommandLine"];
    }

    String script_pid_str = (new Regex("--scriptpid-(.+?) ")).Match(commandLine).Groups[1].Value;

    if (!script_pid_str.Equals("") && Convert.ToInt32(script_pid_str).Equals(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id))
    {
        CurrentBrowserPID = processes[p].Id;
        CurrentBrowserHwnd = processes[p].MainWindowHandle;
        break;
    }
}
```

**CurrentBrowserHwnd** should contain the HWND of your Chrome window.

**CurrentBrowserPID** should contain the Process ID of your Chrome window.